# mysql historical data and record id

Tags: php, mysql, database, transactions

I am setting up a new part of an application with historical data requirements for the transactions table in mysql. Originally in old version transactions were not historical, with structure like this:

```
id|buyerid|prodid|price|status
```

And other fields, with the id being referenced in links to access Transaction Details page, as well as used as foreign key in other tables across the application to reference particular transactions for various purposes.

Now the requirement is to answer reporting questions like `"Show all transaction that had particular status Feb 2014"` AND `"What did a transaction look like in Feb 2014"`.

The new design I'm testing at the moment is below:

```
id|buyerid|prodid|price|status|active|start_date|end_date
```

Where `active` used to indicate latest record, `start` is when it is created, no records to be modified instead end date populated and a new record created with same details plus the modification.

Now the question is - what to do about transaction id field? Because in this new design it is more of a history id, and can not be used for a foreign key across the application since it is going to change with every update.

I can think of two options:

1. Create a separate table, `transaction_ids` with just one column, primary key autoincrement `tid`, and a foreign key column in the main transactions table for `tid` - Every time a brand new transaction is created, insert the ids table and use that id for the tid to trace this particular transaction across the system.
2. The `buyerid` and `prodid` combination is always unique in my application, no buyer can get the same product twice.

Is the second solution better? Does anyone know of a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is called [Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html).
Think in terms of events changing the status of your transaction, rather than tracing the status itself in time.
You still have your transaction with its own primary key, and you rebuild the current (or past) status applying each event.

I would also suggest you to start coding your business models, and only after that, to think about the persistence and the best way to map it to a database.

Answer (score 0):

Second Solution looks better although I will say that there is a lot of ambiguity in your question.

I am saying that second solution is better because the `transaction_ids` table which you are talking about in solution 1 is basically *REDUNDANT*. It is not solving any purpose. Even if the transaction id is repeating itself in the transaction table, it does not mean that you need to have a separate table to generate the ids and make it as PK-FK relation. Most probably you will still be querying the data by user-id and prod-id and not by transaction-id

Basically what you need is some kind of audit history table where you insert a record for every operation/transaction/modification done and capture some basic details like - Username, Date/time, old value, new value etc. You do not need status or start date and end date columns. Once a record is inserted in this audit history table then it is never going to be touched again.

You will have to design your report carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Taking two previous answers into consideration, here is the solution I will go with: All of the data updates in my application come through one single function, that is already set up to audit particular fields of my choosing, so I will mark the transaction `status` to be audited among the others. Table structure for the audit table is similar to this:

```
|id|table|table_id|column|old_val|new_val|who|when|
```

Only that there is a bit more advanced object mapping via object id's instead of simple table name. I can then use this data in a Join to the main, normal not historical transactions table to provide the reporting required.